# What does it take for an application to send out an email?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, email

I am attempting to make a very small web app (in javascript/jquery with possible db backend using sql to call through js). Part of this is a form where a recipient's email is entered and the form will email them from my app's address.

What do I need to know to get something like this set up? How do I configure a form to specify that the sender is the App and what address to use ect? Should I use a MailChimp API (if they have one) or something else entirely?

Thanks

Comment: Will you be using a backend with any particular language? If you know how to make HTTP POSTs with JSON, you should check out [PostageApp](http://postageapp.com) because we make it pretty easy to do that. I even built our jQuery plugin, but it's not for production purposes. :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to an SMTP server to route the e-mail through?

If so, you could just setup a server side (php/.net) to handle the form.  Use regular expressions to verify the e-mail address is valid, and then route it through the SMTP server.

Comment: I believe most web hosting comes with access to an SMTP server? I haven't registered a site for this yet nor researched hosting. If access to SMTP is not a typical include then I guess it is something I should specifically look for?

Comment: Your browser doesn't come with an SMTP server I don't believe.  You can setup a default mail program through your browser, which has access to an SMTP server.

Answer (score 0):

You should send the mail from a server side script. PHP, Ruby, Python, Java, all have native support for sendinqg mail, and good libraries to hide hard things and common pitfalls.

You could try to "send a mail" client side, using a mailto: address or some other magic in the form, but it's far from reliable, especially considering that a lot of people use webmail and does not have anyting picking up a mailto: link.